# How can a weak base act as a strong nucleophile (and vice versa)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilicity

1. Carboxylate ion ($\ce{RCOO-}$) is a weak base as the negative charge on oxygen is delocalised due to resonance. So, it has less tendency to donate lone pair of electrons to H+ ion. Similarly, it has less tendency to donate lone pair of electrons to a carbocations. But in my textbook, it is given that, it acts as a weak base but strong nucleophile. Why does it act as strong nucleophile?
2. LDA (lithiumdiisopropylamide) is a strong bulky base. Why it is considered as a weak nucleophile?

Comment: Nucleophilicity and basicity aren't the same concept.

Comment: Nucleophilicity is tendency of a nucleophile to donate electron pair to carbocation,isn't it ?

Comment: Nucleophilicity is a kinetic concept. Basicity could be kinetic or thermodynamic.

Comment: Sorry sir. I didn't understand you.

Comment: Right. And I think that's your problem. You're confusing two separate concepts that have some overlap. One does not imply the other or vice versa.

Comment: LDA is a strong base, but it is bulky. A nucleophile must have the capacity to attack a electron deficient centre and form a bond. But if it is bulky, it cannot form a strong bond, as the nearby atoms would hinder it. So, LDA becomes a bad nucleophile.